# Unable to get Param in Afnetworking 3.0 during Post (Iphone)

Tags: iphone, afnetworking

I am using following code for getting data from Php server. I want to pass id to the the URL but AfNetworking not getting combine url and id.

```
 - (void)requestServerWithMethod: (NSURL )baseURL andParams:(NSDictionary   )params
{
if (![self isReachable]) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Please check your internet connection and try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];

    return;
}

NSLog(@"params: %@", params);

NSString *url = [baseURL absoluteString];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];// change json response
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Content-Type" forHTTPHeaderField:@"text/html"];
//        UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];  //using for show loader
//        MBProgressHUD *hud= [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:window animated:YES];
//      hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
//     hud.activityIndicatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

//  hud.labelText = @"Loading...";
[manager POST:url parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * Nonnull task, id  Nullable JSON) {
    NSLog(@"success!");

    [_delegate serverDidReceiveResponse:JSON];
    //   [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:window animated:YES];

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask  _Nullable task, NSError  _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);

    [_delegate serverDidReceiveError:error];
    //   [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:window animated:YES];
}];
```

I have checked Json Response and i am getting following response :

```
{"order_list":[{ 
        "order_id":"15",
        "order_num":"160621-100712-8872",
                    "order_date":"2016-06-21 10:07:12",    
        "customer_name":"Ravinder "},{ 
        "order_id":"13",
        "order_num":"160531-095925-9381",
                    "order_date":"2016-05-31 09:59:25",    
        "customer_name":"Ravinder "}]}
```

Comment: please post error what you are getting ?

Comment: Sir i am not getting any error i just want to combine my url and id together for eg : www.myurl.com/index/ is my url and i want to pass id just like www.myurl.com/index/myidhere but its not getting combine , the url and the id is showing separately .

Comment: did you check using GET request in AFNetworking ?

Comment: not yet but i can try now and after i will tell you

Comment: i have used get method also but i am getting this error : error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0

Comment: And one more thing the Json is in right format

Comment: check your request here https://www.hurl.it/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115401/discussion-between-rushabh-and-preet-jay).